# Calling an executable from a Spring Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, design-patterns

I have a Spring application that will need to occasionally produce database backup files. This can be accomplished by calling a MySQL executable called mysqldump. Aside from having to ensure that this executable is available to the application during integration testing and is available in the Docker image the spring app gets built into, are there any obvious reasons why this is a bad design? And if so how would you work around it?

Edit: Just clarifying, I already have implemented this behavior, I’m just curious if anyone sees this as a bad design. That is, having your spring code rely on some external executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute any system command with something like the following, using [`java.lang.Runtime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and [`java.lang.Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump <args>");
process.waitFor(); // Wait until end (blocks the thread)
int result = process.exitValue(); // Exit value of the process
if (result != 0) {
    ...Something was wrong, so...
}
```

As this blocks the thread, you might execute it in a separate one, but as it's a needed system call, I don't see any particular reason wich make feel me unfomfortable.

You always can put a dummy executable returning a controlled error code under the `PATH` of the testing environment so it did't fail, or it did fail on tests. Though I don't see the need of testing the `mysqldump` behaviour since it's provided software.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, I actually have it implemented much like this already. I’ll add a clarification to the question, but I was more so asking is doing this a bad design?